# CDI Error for interceptor on Websphere 8.5

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere, cdi, java-ee-6, websphere-8

I have just enabled CDI on Websphere 8.5.5 and added interceptors

In beans.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/
XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemeLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://
java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
<interceptors>
    <class>com.example.jaxrs.SecurityChecked</class>
</interceptors>
</beans>
```

SecurityChecked annotation

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Inherited;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.interceptor.InterceptorBinding;

@Inherited
@InterceptorBinding
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SecurityChecked {
}

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptor;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

@Interceptor
@SecurityChecked
public class SecurityCheckInterceptor {

 @AroundInvoke
 public Object checkSecurity(InvocationContext context) throws Exception {
    /*
     * check the parameters or do a generic security check before invoking
     * the original method
     */
    Object[] params = context.getParameters();

    /* if security validation fails, you can throw an exception */
    System.out.println("in securitycheck interceptor");

    /* invoke the proceed() method to call the original method */
    Object ret = context.proceed();

    /* perform any post method call work */
    return ret;
}
}
```

In JAX-RS class as below

```
@GET
@com.example.jaxrs.SecurityChecked
public String checkInterceptor(String hello) {
    return "Hello world!";
}
```

When i deploy EAR, i get below error.

WebContainerL I WebContainerLifecycle startApplication OpenWebBeans Container is starting...

[10/15/14 14:53:15:259 EDT] 00000067 BeansDeployer E BeansDeployer deploy                                 org.apache.webbeans.exception.WebBeansConfigurationException: Given class : interface com.example.jaxrs.SecurityChecked is not a interceptor class

Any suggestions what would be the cause of this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says it all. `SecurityChecked` is not an interceptor, but a mere **annotation** used for interceptor binding.The interceptor is `SecurityCheckInterceptor` so your beans.xml should contain:

```
<interceptors>
    <class>com.example.jaxrs.SecurityCheckInterceptor</class>
</interceptors>
```

Regards,
Svetlin

Comment: OOPS! my bad, let me fix that. Thanks!